# Value from async function in URL inside Javascript fetch

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

The below code is inside a react native application:

Let's say I have the below function in API.js file:

```
export function getUsers() {
    return fetch(BASE_URL+'/users')
    .then(response => {
        return response;
    })
}
```

My application's BASE URL is dynamic or can be customized by the user. Which means, I am keeping this value in AsyncStorage of my application.

Which means, AsyncStorage.getItem('BASE_URL') holds the value for my actual BASE_URL. Problem is, the getItem function itself is a promise function. That is only wrapping it to a promise syntax will make it work. For example,

```
AsyncStorage.getItem('BASE_URL').then(url => {
    console.log(url) //gets the URL here properly
});
```

My problem is, how to actually replace the BASE_URL variable in the fetch request with this value?

Remember, API.js file is not a 'component'. It just holds export functions for different API endpoints.

Comment: Why cant you pass the BASE_URL as parameter to the getusers function and call it inside .then of getItem?

Comment: Ah. Nice idea. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [promise chaining](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Using_promises#Chaining), where the result of `AsyncStore#getItem` will be used as input to `fetch` call. The linked document explain the situation that you are facing quite nicely

> A common need is to execute two or more asynchronous operations back to back, where each subsequent operation starts when the previous operation succeeds, with the result from the previous step. We accomplish this by creating a promise chain.

So, changes that you need in you given code is

```
export function getUsers() {
  return AsyncStorage.getItem('BASE_URL').then(url => {
    return fetch(url+'/users').then(response => response.json());
  }); 
}
```

You can use the `getUsers()` without worrying about the `BASE_URL`. This also ensures the separation of concern.

Hope this will help!